# How to fix warnings on Cypress run via custom Windows Powershell arguments?

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell, cypress

I have the following Powershell script

I NEED to pass arguments because I'm using another software to trigger Cypress (Uipath)

```
Param(


    $RunType="--headed",
    $ProductCode="WR",
    $TestFile="cypress/integration/dongle/1-purchase.js"

   )


cd C:\Users\daniel\Desktop\senna-tests\cypress-cast

npx cypress run $RunType --env code= + $ProductCode --spec + $TestFile


# If running in the console, wait for input before closing.
if ($Host.Name -eq "ConsoleHost")
{
    Write-Host "Press any key to continue..."
    $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyUp") > $null
}
```

***It works but I get this ugly warning and I would like to fix the problem:***

[image]

‼ Warning: It looks like you're passing --spec a space-separated list of arguments:

"+ cypress/integration/dongle/1-purchase.js"

This will work, but it's not recommended.

If you are trying to pass multiple arguments, separate them with commas instead:
  cypress run --spec arg1,arg2,arg3

The most common cause of this warning is using an unescaped glob pattern. If you are
trying to pass a glob pattern, escape it using quotes:
  cypress run --spec "**/*.spec.js"

Comment: I'm not familiar with the application, but I assume this is just a command line utility. Sometimes, with similar utilities, it is better to pass the arguments as an array. What's a sample line you would run if you were doing this manually from the command prompt?

Comment: npx cypress run --headed --env code=WR --spec "cypress/integration/dongle/1-purchase.js"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad you found a solution, sorry about the delay in replying. I can't verify it, but usually using an array for arguments stops some issues with command line utilities - I use something similar for utilities by some storage vendors.

Just a suggestion:

```bsh
$RunType = "--headed"
$ProductCode = "code=WR"
$TestFile = "cypres/integration/dongle/1-purchase.js"

$cypArgs = @()
$cypArgs = $cypArgs + "cypress"
$cypArgs = $cypArgs + "run" + "$RunType"
$cypArgs = $cypArgs + "--env" + "$ProductCode"
$cypArgs = $cypArgs + "--spec" + "$TestFile"
& npx.exe $cypArgs
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by removing the plus, replacing for comas.
Also, I was able to fix a problem in the variable product code (it was not accepting = directly so it put it as a variable).

```
Param(


    $RunType="--headed",
    $ProductCode="code=WR",
    $TestFile="cypress/integration/dongle/1-purchase.js"

   )


cd C:\Users\daniel\Desktop\senna-tests\cypress-cast

npx cypress run $RunType --env, $ProductCode --spec , $TestFile


# If running in the console, wait for input before closing.
if ($Host.Name -eq "ConsoleHost")
{
    Write-Host "Press any key to continue..."
    $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyUp") > $null
}
```